# Jade adding quote to data variable

Tags: pug

For some reason Jade seems to add the HTML entity for a double quote to the start and end of the _id string when it's not concatenated with an empty string.

Jade:

```
var post = {_id: ObjectId("551ce90c036474a3805e30cf")};
button(data-id=post._id, data-action='give') Give
```

HTML:

```
<button data-id="&quot;551ce90c036474a3805e30cf&quot;" data-action="give">Give</button>
```

Jade:

```
var post = {_id: ObjectId("551ce90c036474a3805e30cf")};
button(data-id='' + post._id, data-action='give') Give
```

HTML:

```
<button data-id="551ce90c036474a3805e30cf" data-action="give">Give</button>``
```

Is there anyway to fix this or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`post._id` is an [object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-objectid-js) which gets [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)'ed that results in the quotation marks.

Use `post.id` it's a string by default.

Comment: Thanks .I have a question :why  id is invisible ? @laggingreflex